# Fifa 16 stops working while checking connection

Tags: technical-issues, fifa-16

Fifa 16 starts normally. I select the profile to use and it starts checking for connection, then it crashes. 
It goes like this: 
[image]

then it follows like this:

[image]

I've already added an exception to windows firewall and to my antivirus, as well as opening the UDP and TCP ports. My pc handles the minimum requirements and i'm running win 7 pro. Does upgrading to win 10 helps?.
Any help on solving this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to start the game without being connected to the wifi and turn it back on when you are in career mode? That worked for me